# Updating OpenSSL on PlanetLab for Tor 2.7.5

Tags: pluggable-transports

I am trying to run a Tor experiment using PlanetLab machines. However, I need to update OpenSSL to a version 1.0.0 or higher to install a recent version of Tor (2.7.5).

The problem is even when I do this, Tor still finds the system's OpenSSL version of 0.9.8b.

My problem is analogous to the following http://lists.planet-lab.org/pipermail/users/2013-November/004305.html

(The end goal is to run pluggable transports such as ScrambleSuit, obfs4, and meek on the PlanetLab machines)